# override tostring()

Tags: java

im implementing a class based on a given GUI and i'm trying to override tostring() in order to display the information on the GUI but i can't get it to work properly.

GUI code

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    try {
        if (game.isAccepted()) {
            String str = "Selected Applicant:\n\n"
                    + currentApplicant.toString() + "\n\nwas ";
            if (game.isBestApplicant()) {
                str += "the BEST.  You Win!";
            } else {
                str += "not the best available.  You Lose.\n\nBest applicant was: \n\n"
                        + game.getBestApplicant();
            }
            display.setText(str);
            showNewGameControls();
        } else {
            display.setText("Current applicant is:\n\n"
                    + currentApplicant.toString()
                    + "\n\nDo you wish to accept or reject?");
            showCurrentGameControls();
        }
    } catch (HiringException e) {
        display.setText(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        display.setText("Unandled Exception: " + e.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

For the class i am implementing, I wrote the following method

```
public String tostring(){
  return currentApplicant;
}
```

Comment: And what does not work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Try `toString` instead. Capitalization is important.

Comment: Java is case sensitive: try `toString()`

Comment: did you extend the super class correctly?

Comment: if you are looking at getting the class information displayed in a `JLabel` or a `JTextField` you should use `<<object>>.setText(currentApplicant)`.

Comment: if I use Applicant.setText(CurrentApplicant) I get null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `toString`, not `tostring`, as Java is case-sensitive. Thus:

```
public String toString()
```

tostring technically isn't the same as toString in Java. Be careful with spelling. If your editor supports it, use `@Override` annotations. `@Override` annotations protect you from failing to override the proper method.